# animate array elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have some functions that return getById getByClass and an array of html elements that have the id or class.  The issue is that I would like to apply such an animation to each element and these arrays, everyone equally and in a single function, and I have this for now.

```
var slideDown = function (elem, to) {
    var e = getById(elem),
        st, i;
    if (e == false) {
        e = getByClass(elem);
    }
    for (var i in e) {
        //alert(e[i].offsetHeight + e[i].nodeName + e[i].textContent.trim());
        st = setInterval(doAnim(e[i]), 1000);

        function doAnim(e, h) {
            h = e.offsetHeight;
            if (h < to) {
                e.style.height = h + "px";
                h++;
                console.log(h);
                doAnim(e[i], h);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that as the animation function within the for loop will run only twice, in this case, the array contains 2 xq items any more, if I put out also runs twice xq for setInterval is within, my question is how to fix this, I mean, like modifying the array elements, without having to go index index. thanks in advance, do not expect answers like USA JQUERY or things like that, I know that jquery does this, but I'm trying to investigate new things but lock me with this regards.

Comment: @gilly3 I am afraid this question was DOA. Your Google translation from Spanish to English did not improve clarity, unsurprisingly. I would bother trying a translation of my own (I think I know Spanish well enough for that), but then again if the OP posts in Spanish they are not going to understand the answers given in English anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `setInterval` takes a function as the first argument.  But, instead of passing a reference to a function, you are *calling* a function that returns `undefined` (ie, it has no return value).  So, `setInterval` receives `undefined` as the first argument.

Instead, you need to pass a function reference:

```
st = setInterval(doAnim(e[i]), 1000);

function doAnim(e, h) {
    return function() {
        h = e.offsetHeight;
        if (h < to) {
            e.style.height = h + "px";
            h++;
            console.log(h);
            doAnim(e[i], h);
        }
    };
}
```

Next, you are iterating a collection using the `for..in` enumerator statement.  This can have unexpected consequences.  Instead, use a regular `for` loop, or `Array.forEach()` (if it is an array).

Lastly, you never terminate your interval.  Rather than wrapping your function logic in an `if` statement, you should put a `clearInterval` in that `if` statement.

Comment: (From your "translation" I would never have gotten that ;-)) Since the `Function` instance referred to by `Array` does have properties of its own, it would be better to refer to prototype methods by their proper path, here `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

Comment: man, you`re freaking genius :P hahaha, really, it worked, you`re awesome, thanks for understanding the translated english :D